# calculate intersection of two polynomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Show that in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, the ideals $(X^3-X^2,X^2Y-X^2, XY-Y, Y^2-Y)$ and $(X^2,Y)\cap (X-1, Y-1)$ coincide. Is this a radical ideal? I can show that $(X^3-X^2,X^2Y-X^2, XY-X, Y^2-Y) \subseteq (X^2,Y)\cap (X-1, Y-1)$, but I don't have an idea on how to proceed proving the inverse, nor how to investigate whether this ideal is radical. Any ideas?

Comment: I might have solved the first part: $(2-Y)Y + (Y-1)(Y-1)=1$ so $(X^2,Y)$ and $(X-1,Y-1)$ are comaximal, therefore $(X^2,Y) \cap (X-1,Y-1) = (X^2,Y) .(X-1,Y-1) $ and elements of the product are sums of $AX^2(X-1)+BY(X-1)+ CX^2(Y-1)+DY(Y-1)$. But I still don't know if this is a radical ieal.

Comment: I'm an idiot. $(X(X-1))^2$ belongs to the ideal, but $X(X-1)$ does not, so not a radical ideal.